# In Access VBA, how do I attach a customized named file to Outlook?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to rename my report so that it can contain company name and the date it was created. My code fails to attache the file because it cannot find the file. Has someone tried this before or any suggestion?

```
Private Sub emailReport_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim fileN As String
Dim todaysD As String
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oItem As Object
Const oMailItem As Long = 0
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oItem = oApp.CreateItem(oMailItem)


todaysD = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")

fileN = "Quantity used by " & CompanyName & " as of " & todaysD & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "reportQuantityUsed", acFormatPDF, fileN

With oItem
.To = ""
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Quantity used report - " & CompanyName
.Body = "Please find attached the quantity of stock used from: " & 
CompanyName
.Attachments.Add (fileN)
.Display
End With
exitErrorHandler:
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: MsgBox Err.Description
GoTo exitErrorHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: I would think you'd need the full path in your `.Attachments.Add` assignment

Comment: Is it possible not to save the file at all?

Comment: Of course you can save the report to PDF. Just need to get the pathing correct for saving and retrieving. You don't show a file path in the fileN variable, just the file name. So where is the file saved, if at all? Include explicit file path in the fileN variable.

Comment: The thing is, the code works well if outlook is open but fails if outlook is not open. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I find that interesting and unexpected. Specify file path where file is saved and retrieve with the same file path.

Comment: Problem is, work computers restrict me from saving files. I could use the temp folder but i understand that it would be a problem when running it on mac. I have used oItem.Parent.Display it launches but nothing happens

Comment: Tried using Shell("OUTLOOK") but this keeps opening a new outlook even if outlook is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional code to open Outlook or use instance already open. My testing shows that when Outlook is opened by Shell the following code to set and open Outlook objects will not work immediately. Re-run the procedure with Outlook left open then code works.

```
Sub EMTest()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application, OMail As Outlook.MailItem
On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Shell ("OUTLOOK")
    'allow enough time for app to completely open
    Dim Start As Double
    Start = Timer
    While Timer < Start + 10
        DoEvents
    Wend
    EMTest
End If
Set OMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
With OMail
    .To = "email address"
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .Display 'email must be displayed for the next line to work to include default signature
    .HTMLBody = "Message." & vbNewLine & .HTMLBody
    '.Send
End With

Set OMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @ June7. I tried this outlook tries to launch but soon disappears from the task bar.

Comment: Consider revised answer.